# Graphing/visualizing a complex parametric plot without using mathematica

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, parametric

I am trying to visualize the parametric plot in $\mathbb{C}$ of the curve $\gamma$ defined for $t\in[-\infty,\infty]$ as
$$\gamma(t)=\exp\left(-t^{2}+\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}i\right).$$

I was wondering if there is a good way to think about this beyond basic intuition like it should be something periodic or a spiral thanks to Euler's formula, or that for large absolute values of $t$ the curve will approach the origin.

Comment: In case you don't care about velocity etc. and just want to visualize the set of points of $\gamma$,  let $t=\tan(x)$, $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$.

Comment: Why tan? I'm not sure I see how it helps.